# iPhone Web Service Communication

Tags: .net, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, web-services

I have been searching around the web all day for the best way to interface my iPhone application with a Linq .NET SOAP web service.

I think that this project is my answer: wsdl2objc
http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions

The software creates several classes.  It looks great, but the documentation is very limited and I am having trouble getting it to work.  Does anyone know of a good tutorial or sample code for me?

Are there any similar projects out there to help with objective c web service digestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like MonoTouch can do .NET on iPhone. Then it won't be a problem to consume web service.

http://monotouch.net

Comment: I don't see why he should use .NET on iPhone.  
Isn't one of the advantages of SOAP to be language/framework agnostic?

Comment: If a guy is already familiar with .NET on the server side development, utilize the same tech on the client side can boost productivity I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think soap protocol too heavy for Iphone enviroment when you play with large amonut data, you should use RestFull-WCF for .net server side that is a good example for you 
[Creating RESTful Web Services with Windows Communication Foundation](http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/10916_3695436_3/Creating-RESTful-Web-Services-with-Windows-Communication-Foundation.htm) and youuse Json object on the client side (i mean objective-c onto Iphone) [Httpriod](http://labratrevenge.com/httpriot/)

My suggestion is if you can use these, you won't have any performance problems.

Good lock